# Can't pull text from xpath selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

so i have this xpath(its inside another document xpvar):

```
tiltakstekst = "//tbody[@data-bind='foreach: WorkOrders']/tr/td/div/div/div/div/div[@class='comments-field-readonly']"
```

Im attempting to pull the text using this code("x" is because its in a for-loop).

```
tiltakstekst = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpvar.tiltakstekst)[x].text
```

the HTML at the end is like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10">
    <div class="comments-field-readonly" data-bind="html: Description" readonly="">360 Realfagbygget – ombygning av rom BU2-117 og BU2-123 til samme rom. - Levering av brannblits, merkes med merkeskilt «brannalarm». 
    </div>
</div>
```

I find and highlight the wanted div class when using the inspector with the xpath i have here inside Chrome, but i cant seem to pull any text from it. I get no text, so i dont even get any errors. When doing the same using CSS_SELECTOR div.comments-field-readonly i get "None" as text.

I have done exactly the same and got it working on other parts of the website, so i dont understand why i dont get the text..
Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably you are missing a delay, you extracting the text from the elements before them are completely loaded. Just for debugging: put a delay of several seconds before the line where you getting these elements. Please let me know if my guess were correct.

Comment: That XPATH makes my eyes bleed. Can you confirm the url, or can you post (somewhere like pastebin, etc) the full page HTML?

Comment: That still didn't work, tried with different values also. The Xpath works, the div gets highlighted in the Chrome inspector. I can't paste the page HTML I'm afraid. Also this is the only place it doesn't work. I have multiple datalines that gets read from the same document without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, the element wasn't visible so I couldn't use .text

Using get_attribute('textContent') solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not always text attribute will have something inside it, so you will have to try this:

```
element.getAttribute('text')
```

Or

```
element.getAttribute('value')
```

And...if that doesn't work you can always find innerHTML.